# Edit and remove a dynamically created list item

Tags: jquery

I've noticed the other threads on stackoverflow regarding this question but none of them seem to have quite close enough to my question for me to get to a solution.

My situation is that I have created a "to-do" list in jquery. Items are dynamically created by adding them to a list.

When you hover over a 'to-do' item in my program, you are given the option to either edit the 'to-do' or to remove it from the list.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
var itemCount=0;

$("#addButton").on('click',function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    var toDoItem= $(".tempText").val();
    $("#todoList").append('<li>'+toDoItem+'<a href="#" class="edit">'+ "&nbsp;&nbsp;Edit me&nbsp;" +'</a><a href="#" class="remove">'+"&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;Remove Me&nbsp;"+'</a></li>');
    $('li').addClass('toDoItem')

    itemCount=itemCount+1;
    $("#count").text(itemCount);
    return(false);
    /*$("#count").text=("li").length;*/
});
    $("#clearButton").on('click',function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    $("li").remove();
    itemCount=0;
    $("#count").text(itemCount);
    return(false);
});


$("ul").on('click','li', function(){
    $(this).remove( );

    });
```

});
When I click on the 'Remove' link or the 'Edit' link, both will remove the item. I only want 'Remove' to take care of removing the item. Any suggestions
I have read over the pages on event delegation but they don't seem to get me anywhere.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of registering the handler to the `li` add it to the remove link(`.remove`) then in the handler find the `li` ancestor of the element and remove it.

```
$("ul").on('click', '.remove', function () {
    $(this).closest('li').remove();
    //or $(this).parent().remove(); since the `li` is the direct parent of the link
});
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/9NJgT/)

Now the problem is, you are binding the handler to the `li` element so any click on the `li` element(including in any of the descending elements) will trigger the handler.

Comment: That's great! Thank you, Arun. I just don't understand why I have to use the .closest method if I am using 'this'. Why doesn't jquery know that I am already specifying the particular 'li'?